# In which file is the version number of CppUTest defined

Tags: numbers, version, cpputest

In which source/include file is the version number of CppUTest (http://cpputest.github.io) defined ?

I have search all files, both .cpp and .h files but could not find anything.

The latest version, according to CppUtest homepage is 3.4 and I want to see if our system is using that or not.

Regards Stefan

Answer (score 0):

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cpputest/N--j9TW667Y

If you use the source distribution, then it is in the configure.ac file.

If you don't have a configure.ac file, then you have an older than 3.4 version :)

Bas